# How to correctly assign data from an array within the collectionview?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, maui

When consuming an API in JSON format, I put the get data in the `ItemsSource`, but the data does not appear on the screen as expected.

```
public class ListPokemons
{
    public Pokemon[] Pokemon { get; set; }
}

public class Pokemon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```
 ListPokemons pokemon = await _restService.GetAllPokemon(GenerateRequestURL(Constants.OpeAPiPokemon));

if (pokemon == null)
{
    return;
}

PokemonAll = pokemon;
```

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PokemonAll}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Pokemon[0].Name}"/>
                    <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Pokemon[0].Name}"/>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Well, I got it here, just put the ItemsSource as PokemonAll.Pokemon, now I can access the data correctly

Answer (score 2):

your bindings are wrong

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Pokemon}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a true MVVM experience, your classes should be observable, e.g.

```xml
public class Pokemon : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
}
```

Then, you can publish a collection of this type from your ViewModel. N.B. It is not necessary to declare your collection as a type on it's own, it's enough to use either `List` or `ObservableCollection`. The latter is preferred if you want your CollectView to subscribe to changes to your collection whilst your app is running:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Pokemon> Pokemons { get; set; } = ObservableCollection<Pokemon>() {
        new Pokemon() { Id = 1, Name = "Pikachu" },
        new Pokemon() { Id = 2, Name = "Charmanda" }
    };
}
```

Then your XAML would be:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Pokemons}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType={x:Type local:Pokemon}>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```